# How to reset CD/DVD drive

Tags: dvd, drive

I'm using a Windows DVD ripping program under Play-On-Linux and every now and then, despite removing the DVD contents from the program, when I click the 'Unmount' in Nautilus a message box pops up saying that the drive is in use and proceed or cancel.  If I proceed then the drive, or something in the system, gets messed up and DVDs no longer get recognized by Ubuntu.  I have to reboot to get the drive back.

Is there anything I can do to reset the drive with out having to reboot the entire system?

Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Also seeing a similar issue, using whipper (fork of morituri).